# 0x800a01bd - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this action - Kendo UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

What am I doing wrong? All I want to do is get some data from an API and display it on the screen:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Kendo UI Test</title>
        <link href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"> </script>
        <script src="js/kendo.web.min.js"> </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="grid"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                var retrievedData = new kendo.data.dataSource({
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "http://puppygifs.tumblr.com/api/read/json",
                            dataType: "json"
                        }
                    }
                });

                $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: retrievedData,
                    pageSize: 10
                });
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The error occurs at this part:

```
var retrievedData = new kendo.data.dataSource({
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "http://puppygifs.tumblr.com/api/read/json",
                            dataType: "json"
                        }
                    }
                });
```

EDIT:

How would I modify the code to capture data from an object that looks like this:

```
[
{
<NotificationNode>k__BackingField: {
isDirty: false,
isRecordAdded: false,
isRecordDeleted: false,
<CaseStatus>k__BackingField: null,
<CaseName>k__BackingField: null,
<CaseType>k__BackingField: null,
<CaseStage>k__BackingField: null,
<CaseNotificationId>k__BackingField: 0,
<CaseId>k__BackingField: 0,
<Comments>k__BackingField: null,
<WarningDays>k__BackingField: 0,
<NotificationDate>k__BackingField: "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
<LetterUrl>k__BackingField: null,
<NotificationId>k__BackingField: 0,
<NotificationDescription>k__BackingField: null,
<NotificationCount>k__BackingField: 1889,
<ParamValue1>k__BackingField: null,
<ParamValue2>k__BackingField: null,
<ParamValue3>k__BackingField: null,
<ParamValue4>k__BackingField: null,
<ParamValue5>k__BackingField: null,
<NotificationStatus>k__BackingField: 0,
<Checked>k__BackingField: false,
notificationTypeId: 1,
notificationType: "Add/Edit Gross Earnings",
actionPageName: null,
param1: null,
param2: null,
param3: null,
param4: null,
param5: null,
dateEntered: "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
whoEntered: 0,
dateChanged: "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
whoChanged: 0
},
<Notifications>k__BackingField: [ ],
<IsExpanded>k__BackingField: false
},
```

Comment: It would be very helpful to know what line of code generates the problem.

Comment: It has to be DataSource (uppercase D)

Comment: @Dr.Molle, we are making progress! that fixed this error. Now how come I don't see anything on the screen? do I need to explicit define the columns of the json to display?

Comment: I'm not familiar with kendo(I never heard about it until your question ). I guess DataSource expects an Array, but the response of tumblr is an Object. You need to set a schema to get the array out of the response: http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-schema.data  (use "posts" instead of "results") . Then you get at least the table-header(unfortunately not the data, can't tell you why, there is an error  "invalid template" ). But however, you must use the dataType "jsonp" as suggested in the (now deleted) answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo on dataSource option, it must be `DataSource`; the data you are reading are from another origin so you to use `jsonp` as `dataType`.

The provided service return a complex set of data you have to read only data to show in grid and bind the data you want to show in your column.

You can do this using [`schema`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-schema.data) and [`columns`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#configuration-columns) parameters.

Code:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      var retrievedData = new kendo.data.DataSource({
          transport: {
              read: {
                  url: "http://puppygifs.tumblr.com/api/read/json",
                  dataType: "jsonp"
              }
          },
          schema: {
              data: "posts"
          }
      });
      $("#grid").kendoGrid({
          dataSource: retrievedData,
          columns: [{
              field: "id",
              title: "ID",
              width: 150
          }, {
              field: "url",
              title: "URL",
              width: 150
          }]
      });
  });
```

Working demo: <sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

Comment: thank you so much Edward. I just dont understand this part: schema: {data: "posts"}. How did you get "posts" ?

Comment: Edward, I edited my post. The object I get back is formatted differently and it's not pulling the data on the grid. Can you give me a hand on how to display the data returned in that format? (with all those "k__BackingField"s)

Comment: The "posts" string is the JSON object contains the list of rows, I found it by checking the provided web method. Your case is different from the provided question...but what is "k__BackingField" can you provide a jsfiddle?